# How to find record and create scope for query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two model

**Artists**

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :photos, :as => :photoable, :dependent => :destroy

   def is_approved?
     self.admin_approve == true
   end
end
```

**Photo**

```
  class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :photoable, :polymorphic => true
  end
```

I want to find photos that (Artists photo) admin_approve is true. How can i write query and scope for that.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: I like [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) gem. It allows to deal with polymorphic joins easily: `Note.joins{notable(Person).articles}`. In your case it would be: `joins{photoable(Artist)}.where{artists.admin_approve == true}`.Try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jdoe, Thank You, But I done following way

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :photoable, :polymorphic => true
    ...
  scope :approve_artists_photo, joins("Inner Join artists on artists.id = photos.photoable_id AND photos.photoable_type = 'Artist'").where("artists.admin_approved = 1")
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add a scope

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :photos, :as => :photoable, :dependent => :destroy

   scope :approved, where(:admin_approve => true)

   def is_approved?
     self.admin_approve == true
   end
end
```

And then get the photos as

```
Artist.approved.photos
```